# replacing parts for Oil leaks on mercedes 230 slk 2001 and time it takes

Tags: mercedes-benz, oil-leak

How long should it take to replace a crankshaft seal and camshaft adjuster magnet on 2001 slk230 mercedes? And, wouldn"t you notice a oil pan gasket leak when you saw other 2 leaks?

Comment: A crankshaft seal replacement is a tough job, it requires the removal of the transmission to reach the seal

Comment: For those looking to close this, there is a definite (non-opinionated) answer to this question ... it's called "book hours". This is an on-topic question (at least that part of it). The other question is subjective, but is reasonable to answer in the affirmative. I don't have access to book hours ... hoping someone else does.

Answer (score 1):

> wouldn"t you notice a oil pan gasket leak when you saw other 2 leaks

Unlikely. Heck, it's tough to pinpoint one oil leak sometimes. If other leak sources are leaking above the leak coming from the oil pan it would be impossible to say whether the leak was from the pan gasket or an above source. Sometimes the best way of going about this is to only fix the spot you know is leaking, clean old oil off, run it for a bit, and then recheck for leaks in other suspected places. It's a chore.

I'm working through this on an W211 E55 at the moment. Mercedes can be leaky beasts.

Answer (score 1):

Removal & Replacement on the camshaft adjuster magnet is 1 hour of labor. The front crankshaft oil seal is 2 hours. The rear crankshaft oil seal is 2.3 hours.